# User with less reputation than expected.

Tags: support, reputation

According to https://math.stackexchange.com/users/54911/twiceler?tab=profile, this guy has 6863 reputation, but he answered a question with 756 upvotes with a +400 bounty.  That should warrant him at least 7000 reputation, but the information proves otherwise.  How?

Comment: There's a cap of 200 reputation per day, so many of those 756 votes didn't count towards their points.

Comment: You cannot get more than 200 points per day. In particular, for answers with lots of upvotes, quite a few of the them don't provide points.

Comment: Links to some further information on this can be found in the [daily-reputation-limit tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/daily-reputation-limit/info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been more or less answered in the comment. To be more precise, you can visit their activity page and see that they got around 200 reputation for four [straight days](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/54911/twiceler?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=15), starting at May 3 '13. If you click on each day, you can see that the "events" are counted 119, 71, 30 and 27 respectively. If you click the "events", you will see that, because the rep cap, some upvotes correspond to no reputation.

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot of reputation tab]

After expansion: [image] $$\vdots$$ [image]